# 1010: Invalid Transaction: Transaction would exhaust the block limits

Tags: benchmarking, weight, error, call

How to specify limit weight for extrinsic?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your extrinsic doing? Can you share the code?

Comment: Did you benchmark it appropriately?

Comment: This one
https://github.com/pendulum-chain/oracle-pallet/blob/master/pallets/dia-oracle/src/lib.rs#L374-L386
@Bruno

Comment: @Bruno what is the reason of 1010 error in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the error reported by polkadot.js UI is informative enough of the issue. The [weight defined for the dispatchable function](https://github.com/pendulum-chain/oracle-pallet/blob/b8c5bd0f0e756d83868f1dd982d45792a662bfd7/pallets/dia-oracle/src/weights.rs#L89) `set_updated_coin_infos` represents a computation longer than one second (1^12 units of weight = 1 second of computation).