# Off-chain worker. Error submitting a transaction to the pool: InvalidTransaction::ExhaustsResources

Tags: parachain, substrate-parachain-template, error, offchain-worker

**Error submitting a transaction to the pool: Transaction pool error: Invalid transaction validity: InvalidTransaction::ExhaustsResources**

It works fine in standalone but in parachain it fails.

Off chain worker in DIA oracle throw an error while tried to send extrinsic.

Comment: thank you so much. yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong weighs are the actual problem.
okay. there reason is the same as [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7342/1010-invalid-transaction-transaction-would-exhaust-the-block-limits)